# invalid app id: CHANGE-ME

Tags: firebase-authentication

I'm setting up authentication through Firebase authentication but I'm getting an error:

```
Invalid App ID: CHANGE-ME
```

I have set up Facebook auth in my Firebase console with the app ID and secret, the same ID that my app have on the Facebook application console. I've also made the app public, turning sandbox mode off. Additionally, I've added Facebook-log on as a product on the Facebook console, and providing a OAuth redirect link from my Firebase Console.

I've also defined the App ID in `strings.xml` and referenced it in my application manifest file:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

Why am I getting this error message?

Answer (score 9):

Code in FirebaseUI-Android/auth/src/main/res/values/config.xml as bellow

```
<string name="facebook_application_id" translatable="false">CHANGE-ME<string/>
```

Hence Overridden the actual value in the my own application.After that it worked fine.

add a line File : string.xml

```
<string name="facebook_application_id" translatable="false">Actual app ID<string/>
```

Above change fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

It looks like firebase is looking for the string "facebook_application_id" but I think most are named "facebook_app_id" instead. I added both of these to my strings and it fixed the issue:

```
<string name="facebook_app_id">APP_ID</string>
<string name="facebook_application_id">APP_ID</string>
```